# Setting Onclick Listener for Adapter View

Tags: java, android, onclick, listener, adapter

I have the following layout file and adapter code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="70dip"
android:background="@drawable/white"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10sp">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/Logo"
android:layout_width="50dip"
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />    
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#FF000000"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:typeface="sans"  
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Logo" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/description"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:layout_below="@id/name"
android:textColor="#0000CC"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Logo" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/address"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:layout_below="@id/description"
android:textColor="#990000"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Logo" 
/>
</RelativeLayout>    

private void showPlaces(Cursor cursor) {

    MyCustomAdapterClass adapter = new MyCustomAdapterClass(this,cursor, true);  
setListAdapter(adapter); 

}
```

Can anyone tell me how I set an onclick listener to detect when someone clicks on an item in my list ?

Thank you !

EDIT Whole main :

```
package org.example.DatabaseImport;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import static android.provider.BaseColumns._ID;
import static org.example.DatabaseImport.Constants.TABLE_NAME;
import static org.example.DatabaseImport.Constants.AREA;
import static org.example.DatabaseImport.Constants.ADDRESS;
import static org.example.DatabaseImport.Constants.UNIQUEID;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class Main extends ListActivity {

private DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView yourList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    yourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                        Log.e("onClick",""+arg1);
                        }   
    });



    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

} catch (IOException ioe) {

    throw new Error("Unable to create database");

}

try {

    myDbHelper.openDataBase();

}catch(SQLException sqle){

    throw sqle;

}

try {

    Cursor cursor = getPlaces();
    showPlaces(cursor);

}

finally {

myDbHelper.close();

}
}

private static String[] FROM = { _ID, AREA, ADDRESS, UNIQUEID};
private static String ORDER_BY = _ID + " ASC";

private Cursor getPlaces() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, ORDER_BY);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;

}

private static int[] TO = {R.id.name, R.id.description, R.id.address, };
private void showPlaces(Cursor cursor) {

    MyCustomAdapterClass adapter = new MyCustomAdapterClass(this,cursor, true); setListAdapter(adapter); 

}
```

And here is main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ListView 
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your whole code. for activity.

Comment: If you want to add setOnClickListener for listview then you should have a listview in your activity. And as per my assumption the layout which you provide is for list item. not for main screen.

Comment: Ah ok - sorry I'm new to this. Is this my list view code (in main) : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ListView 
 android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: now in your activity define this listview and then set adapter for this listview, after that in adapter's getview() method just inflate the layout of listitem(you declared here) in view. and for listview just setOnclicklistener() method. Simple :-)

Comment: How do I define the listview ? This crashes.  ListView yourList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

Comment: that's why I told you to provide whole code for your activity and main xml file.

Comment: make change here then try <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: Added in activity code and xml. Thanks for your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3199/discussion-between-ohnomycoco-and-user370305)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

private DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {
      myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
    myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){

    throw sqle;

}

try {

    Cursor cursor = getPlaces();
    showPlaces(cursor);

}

finally {

myDbHelper.close();

}
}

private static String[] FROM = { _ID, AREA, ADDRESS, UNIQUEID};
private static String ORDER_BY = _ID + " ASC";

private Cursor getPlaces() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, ORDER_BY);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;

}

private static int[] TO = {R.id.name, R.id.description, R.id.address, };
private void showPlaces(Cursor cursor) {

    MyCustomAdapterClass adapter = new MyCustomAdapterClass(this,cursor, true); setListAdapter(adapter); 

}

@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
        Log.e("Position",""+position);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Finn. I assume I need to add in an ID for the list view ? I.e android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout" at the top of code I listed ?

Comment: The xml you posted is the xml for each item on the list. You need to add it to the ListView that contains your items.

Comment: I don't have a list view - I'm using an adapter ?

Comment: Adapter is for wrap data in your listview. For displaying data in list you should have a listview.

Comment: user370305 is right. 
Does your activity extend ListView or ListActivity? This might be the reason why you can't seem to find your listView :)

Comment: You might get along with just implementing OnItemClickListener and override the onItemClick interface.

@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
  Log.e("Position:",""+position);
  
 }

This should solve your problem...